# If I am learning C++, is it a problem to learn C++11/14 when C++20 is the most modern version?

Tags: c++

I am a fairly new programmer, with only a little bit of python experience. I learned python because I wanted to see if I would enjoy programming, and now I love it. I want to learn C++, and according to [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) a really great book is [Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DUW4BMS), a book by the creator of C++. My only concern is that the book is only updated for C++11 and 14, while I read C++20 is a major change("C++20 will be the next big C++ standard after C++11. As C++11 did it, C++20 will change the way we program modern C++" is what I read. I was looking at the changes, but honestly I don't understand a single one). Will learning through this book be a problem for me in the future, or will learning with C++11/14 not really impact me concerning C++20?

Comment: Completely opinionated question. IMHO, since you're still in the stages of learning most of the fundamentals of the language won't noticeably change for minor or major versions. "I was looking at the changes, but honestly I don't understand a single one." - because those changes are likely for advanced concepts in the language that you haven't encountered yet. Just choose a book that explains the fundamentals of the language in a way that you understand, then when you get to advanced topics, you'll notice the changes and be comfortable to understand them.

Comment: Probably a subjective question. But the basics aren't going to change. So learn them. Each C++ version adds new things, and those are fine on their own merits, but personally I recommend learning from the ground up (interpret that as it suits you).

Comment: I started learning and using C++ more than 20 years ago. I'm still learning today. It isn't like you're going to read one book and be a master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think learning C++14 will hurt you at all.  It's still very "modern" in the grand scheme of C++ history.  The newer C++ versions tend to build on previous versions with more advanced features, but if you're just getting started with C++, the basics will be the same going back to at least the 90's.  If anything, you'll have a much better appreciation for why the improvements in the newer versions are actually considered improvements.